# Как быстрее всего проверить наличие файла на сервере?

Tags: windows, ассемблер

Ос Винда, Разрядность 32. 
Сейчас использую FindFirstFileA Есть что-то быстрее?
Перепроверил, GetFileAttributesA работает быстрее, в большинстве случаев
Есть что-то быстрее?

Comment: А Вы уже профилировали? Может нужно алгоритм поменять?

И "проверить наличие на сервере" - сервер - это просто комп или имеется ввиду проверка по сети?

Comment: Локальная сеть. Несколько серверов

Comment: GetFileAttributes медленней FindFirstFileA быстрей. Проверка наличия файла самое узкое место в программе. Ибо, ежели файл на самом компе, то ищет быстро. Также использовал SearchPathA , медленный вариант ( Ибо требует аж 6 параметров )

Comment: Распаралелить? Тогда в целом, что 5, что 10 серверов, разницы особой не будет. Правда на сотне серверов уже будет медленее, но не настолько.

Comment: Где я писал про распараллеливание? Это не требуется

Comment: Я понимаю, что Вы хотите приготовить яичницу без яиц. Но это немного сложно. В Вашей задаче основное время съедают сетевые задержки. И их побороть "правильной функцией" нельзя. Но так как "сервера" работают независимо, то распаралеливание на запрашивающей стороне сильно ускорит работу.

Comment: Если с распараллеливанием быстрее, то как это сделать? Через потоки, не?

Comment: через потоки - самое простое пока. Можно и другими способами, тут все зависит от фантазии.

Comment: Другими? Какими?

Comment: например, каждый сервер индексирует свои файлы сам и отправляет данные о изменении файлов в общую базу.

Answer (score 1):

GetFileAttributes() - один вызов API вместо FindFirstFile()/FindClose(). Будет ли быстрее - надо мерять, но кода точно меньше.

Comment: Медленней, замерял

Comment: Это странно, но пусть будет так.

Comment: Суммарно, медленней. Ежели отдельно судить, быстрей, да, но не всегда. Где-то в 5% случаев финд ищет быстрей вместе с закрытием